# Google Sheets dynamic filtering of editable data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter

**I have :** a Google Sheets dataset with a D column of checkboxes TRUE/FALSE

[image]

**I can :** use the built-in "Create a filter" tool to show only TRUE/FALSE rows, both, or none (by checking on/off TRUE/FALSE or through a Custom Formula as in picture below).

[image]

**I want :** a dynamic (update when user checks off a row) ***but still editable*** filtering.

**I tried (results are "as far as I know", cf. questions) :**

- Using the built-in "Create a filter" tool => not dynamic.
- Using `=FILTER()` => creates a view-only (not editable) copy of the original dataset.
- Using `FILTER()` through scripts => still limited to view-only.
- Searching every option possible and found [something about the "Basic Filter"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters).

**Questions :**

1. Is the built-in "Create a filter" tool indeed limited by its non-dynamic nature ?
2. Is the `FILTER()` function indeed limited to creating a non editable view of the original dataset ?
3. Is the "Basic Filter" in the link above the one I am using manually with the "Create a filter" built-in tool ?
4. How to achieve a dynamic filtering of my original editable dataset ? Any inkling/advice towards a solution will be appreciated, I'll update with a full solution myself once I'm done !

Comment: First, if I misunderstood your question, I apologize. About `How to achieve a dynamic filtering of my original editable dataset ?`, I thought that in this case, the OnEdit trigger of Google Apps Script instead of the basic filter might be able to be used. Is this included in your goal? But, in this case, for example, if you want to show only rows with the checked checkboxes of column "D", how do you want to show all rows by a reset? When all checkboxes are unchecked, all rows with the checkboxes are hidden. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike The use case is akin to a "to do list" where the user checks off a row once done, and doesn't want to see said row anymore most of the time (but might want to access "done rows" at times, which would be handled through options "Show/Hide completed rows"). Yes, I'm planning to use the onEdit() trigger, but so far I couldn't manage to filter editable data successfully, hence the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood `but might want to access "done rows" at times, which would be handled through options "Show/Hide completed rows"` and `Yes, I'm planning to use the onEdit() trigger`. And, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly `but so far I couldn't manage to filter editable data successfully`, for example, when the OnEdit trigger is used, the basic trigger can be refreshed. By this, the basic trigger can be dynamically used. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike This sounds... wonderfully perfect (refreshing the basic filter). How to ?!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a simple sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in the comment, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to refresh the basic filter when the checkboxes of column "D" is changed.

#### Prerequisite

In this sample, it supposes that your Spreadsheet has already had the checkboxes, and column "D" has already set the basic filter. Please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And please set your sheet name and save the script.

When you use this script, please check or uncheck the checkbox of column "D". By this, the script is automatically run by the simple trigger of OnEdit.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const col = 4; // column "D"

  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != col) return;
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (!filter) {
    Browser.msgBox("Please set basic filter to column D.");
    return;
  }
  const r = filter.getRange();
  const criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(col).copy();
  filter.remove();
  r.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
}
```

- When you check or uncheck the checkbox of column "D", `onEdit` is automatically run. And, the basic filter of column "D" is refreshed.
- When the following modification is run, the refresh of the filter might be smooth.

  - From

    ```
      const r = filter.getRange();
      const criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(col).copy();
      filter.remove();
      r.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      const criteria = filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(col);
      filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(col, criteria);
    ```

#### Note:

- This `onEdit` is automatically run with the simple trigger. Please don't directly run the script with the script editor. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Doesn't work yet for my actual dataset, but works fine on a basic simple test sheet.
So a simple "filter refresh" script as I've seen in many questions here was the answer (crying!).
Thank you for your time and very detailed answer with safeguards everywhere ;-)

Comment: @klonaway Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad that this approach is useful for your situation. And, I could correctly understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too. By the way, from this answer, I added a tag of `google-apps-script` to the tags of the question.

Comment: @klonaway I added one modification point. Please confirm it. In the additional modification, the refresh of the filter might be smooth, because the basic filter is overwritten instead of removed.